# Как сделать активным input type data чтобы календарь был всегда виден

Tags: html5, вёрстка, html-form

Этот инпут висит в попапе, нужно сделать так чтобы при открытии попапа - он уже так выглядел

[image: скрин как надо]

Есть ли какие-то дефолтные решения, не хочется костыли городить?

Comment: Я знаю за бутстрап, если что, и знаю что там есть соответствующий виджет, но в данном случае бутстрап не является решением. Вся верстка строится на гридах и флексах, и тащить бутс только ради календаря  -  увольте

Answer (score 0):

Мне помог этот виджет. При правильном его использовании - у меня получился почти такой же результат
https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/